# Scaling polygons in vector grid around polygon centers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, polygon-creation, centroids, scale-factor

I have a aerial image with a vector grid overlaid in QGIS. Is it possible to scale the individual polygons (scale all of them by the same size) around their individual centroids? For example, to cut out non vegetative pixels?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From QGIS 3.24, you can use the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) tool with the `scale` function.

```
scale(
    geometry:=$geometry, 
    x_scale:=0.5, 
    y_scale:=0.7
)
```

[image]

Comment: I can not find `scale()` function in [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html)

Comment: Looks like it is a recent addition, added in 3.24: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#feature-scale-function. I have added the version number to my answer. @BERA, it is probably worth keeping your answer for users of older QGIS versions.